# Custom Module API get CDATA Error

Tags: magento2, api

i got this error at localhost/rest/V1/hello/name/Jim.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<error>
<messages>
<error>
<data_item>
<code>500</code>
<message>
<![CDATA[
Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor::resolveFullyQualifiedClassName() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php on line 535 and defined in /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php:640 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(535): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor->resolveFullyQualifiedClassName(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\ClassReflection), NULL) #1 /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php(139): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor->getParamType(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\ParameterReflection)) #2 /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(156): Magento\Framework\Reflection\MethodsMap->getMethodParams('VENDOR\\New...', 'name') #3 /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(101): Magento\Fram' in '/var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php' on line 640
]]>
</message>
<trace>
<![CDATA[ Trace is not available. ]]>
</trace>
</data_item>
</error>
</messages>
</error>
```

etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/hello/name/:name" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\News\Api\NewsInterface" method="name"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\News\Api\NewsInterface" type="Vendor\News\Model\NewsManagement" />
</config>
```

api/NewsInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\News\Api;

interface NewsInterface
{
    public function name($name);
}
```

Model/NewsManagement.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\News\Model;
use Vendor\News\Api\NewsInterface;

class NewsManagement implements NewsInterface
{
    public function name($name) {
        return "Hello, " . $name;
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Type hint your argument as string

Comment: What is mean it exactly?

Comment: dock block about the `name` method in the `NewsInterface`. Also you you can declare the method like this `public function name(string $name): string`

Answer (score 2):

I missed the doc block in my PHP. You need to put that comments just above the function declaration.

```
/**
* @api
* @param string 
* @return string 
*/
```